# Why does my Gremlin migration query only add one edge from each vertex?

Tags: java, groovy, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I'm trying to add a `Subscription` vertex ([Org-Sends->Subscription<-Receives-User]) for each [Org-Manages->User] where one is not already present. I wrote this traversal, which appears to select the values I'm interested in:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Org')
  .match(
    __.as('oV').out('Manages').as('uV'),
    not(__.as('oV').out('Sends').in('Receives').as('uV')
  )
```

I get a set of tuples `oV,uV` with the relevant vertex pairs. So far, so good.

I then appended this:

```
.sideEffect(
  addV('Subscription').as('newV')
    .select('oV').addE('Sends').to(select('newV'))
    .select('uV').addE('Receives').to(select('newV'))
)
```

I expected, for each of the pairs `oV,uV`, to get the relevant structure set up. Instead, *all of the Subscription vertices* are created, and *all of the Receives edges* are created, but *only one Sends edge per Org* is created.

As far as I can tell, the "input" to `sideEffect` is a set of "rows" with lots of duplicated Org vertices. I also tried inserting `select('oV', 'uV')` before the `sideEffect` with no change in behavior. **Why is the `addE`, but *only* the `addE`, short-circuiting after seeing a particular `oV`?**

---

I am executing this against Amazon Neptune, and I ran `explain` in the console. This was the explanation I got, which appears to match my written traversal:

```
Final Traversal[
    NeptuneGraphQueryStep(Vertex),
    NeptuneTraverserConverterStep,
    MatchStep(
        AND,[
            [MatchStartStep(oV), VertexStep(OUT,[Manages],vertex), MatchEndStep(uV)],
            [MatchStartStep(oV), WhereTraversalStep([NotStep([WhereStartStep, VertexStep(OUT,[Sends],vertex), VertexStep(IN,[Receives],vertex), WhereEndStep(uV)])]), MatchEndStep, MatchEndStep]
        ]
    ),
    TraversalSideEffectStep([
        AddVertexStep({$migration=[asdf], label=[Subscription]})@[newV],
        SelectOneStep(last,oV),
        NoOpBarrierStep(2500),
        AddEdgeStep({~to=[[SelectOneStep(last,newV)]], label=[Sends]}),
        SelectOneStep(last,uV),
        NoOpBarrierStep(2500),
        AddEdgeStep({~to=[[SelectOneStep(last,newV)]], label=[Receives]})
    ])
]
```

Comment: I did quite a few experiments (shown below) but was unable to recreate what I believe you are describing. Perhaps you could take a look at my answer and see if there is some nuance I am missing that would make my experiment different.

Comment: Thanks, @KelvinLawrence, and I'll try to take a look tomorrow. The production query is more complex, but only by attaching properties, and I confirmed with the `match`-part that the input to `sideEffect` does in fact return all of the expected pairs unrolled.

Answer (score 1):

Using the air-routes data set I attempted to simulate your query using both Amazon Neptune and TinkerGraph. In each case everything seems to be working as intended. I got all of the edges I would expect to get created. Here is what I used for testing.

The air routes data set includes routes without a matching return. So I used some of those to simulate some where we wanted to create some edges.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('airport','region','GB-ENG').
......1>   match(__.as('a').out('route').as('b'),
......2>         __.not(__.as('b').out('route').as('a'))).
......3>   select('a','b').by('code')
==>[a:MAN,b:ANU]
==>[a:LTN,b:ORY]
```

Using that foundation I added your `sideEffect` step. Note that there is a an unwanted comma between the `addE` steps in your query which I removed below.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('airport','region','GB-ENG').
......1>   match(__.as('a').out('route').as('b'),
......2>         __.not(__.as('b').out('route').as('a'))).
......3>   sideEffect(addV('Subscription').as('newV').
......4>              select('a').addE('Sends').to(select('newV')).
......5>              select('b').addE('Receives').to(select('newV')))

==>[a:v[84],b:v[219]]
==>[a:v[206],b:v[107]]
```

We can then verify that all of the expected structure was created.

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('Subscription')
==>v[61367]
==>v[61370]


gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('Subscription').inE().outV().path()
==>[v[61367],e[61369][219-Receives->61367],v[219]]
==>[v[61367],e[61368][84-Sends->61367],v[84]]
==>[v[61370],e[61372][107-Receives->61370],v[107]]
==>[v[61370],e[61371][206-Sends->61370],v[206]]
```

Note that the query can be rewritten without `match` using `where` steps which will likely result in a more efficient query execution plan.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('airport','region','GB-ENG').as('a').
......1>       out('route').as('b').
......2>       where(__.not(out('route').as('a'))).
......3>       select('a','b').
......4>       by('code')
==>[a:MAN,b:ANU]
==>[a:LTN,b:ORY]
```

Comment: Thanks for catching the spurious comma; that was a posting error here. I note that in your example, the traversal is both to-and-from the same kind of vertex (airport), and that it doesn't have the intermediate vertex that's being traversed through. You're certainly right about the option of collapsing to a `where`, but this is for a one-time migration, and the logic is more clearly readable to reviewers with the `match` syntax.